# css input and button zoom in

Tags: html, css, forms, web

i was trying to build a website containing forms with buttons. when i zoom in the texts value of the inputs and the buttons get bigger.below is my css:

```
.id{
    position: relative;
    background: rgb(174,212,248);
    height: 2%;
    width: 179%;
    margin: 14% -21%;
    border: none;
    padding: 10%;
    font-size: 27;
    font-family: cursive;
    text-align: center;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 180px;
    box-shadow: -2px 5px 2px cadetblue;
}

.search{
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: -8% 95%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 3%;
    width: 40%;
    border: 0;
    background-color: white;
    position: inherit;
    box-shadow: -2px 5px 2px cadetblue;
}
```

and here is my html :

```
<div>
    <form method="POST" action="check_exist.php">
    <input  class='id' type="text" placeholder="Patient Id" name="patient_id" id="patien_id"/>
    <input class="search" type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
    </div>
```

can anyone help me fixing this issue ? thanks you

**Question**

At certain zoom level's the text inside the button for example doesn't appear anymore, How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: @JadDaud Isn't the point of zooming to increase the size of the text?

Comment: you're right @AbstractChaos but at certain zoom level the text inside the button for example doesn't appear anymore

Comment: @JadDaud thank you for clarification, I updated your question for you.

Answer (score 0):

i think problem is your font size `font-size: 27px;` is fixed make it small using media screen....

and sorry in advance if it is not that problem

```
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .id{font-size:18px;}
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) and ( max-height:1200px)
{
    .id{font-size:22px;}
}

@media screen and (min-width:1201px)
{
    .id{font-size:27px;}
}
```

Comment: keyframe is for animation , how can we use it for text size. Please advise

Comment: @media (max-width: 480px) {
.id{font-size:18px;}
}

Comment: @media screen and (min-width:801px) and ( max-width:1600px){ .id{font-size:27px;}}

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tested on search button to see if the font size wont change, at certain zoom the button get smaller for a while then it gets bigger at the same size(300%) :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yd3syo4j/ this is you code please check link and tell me what is the problem